# Are there complexity theory consequences of the collapse NEXP=EXP^NP?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, time-complexity

It is clear that $NEXP\subseteq EXP^{NP}$, as a TM with exponential run time can simply query the NP oracle with an exponentially long query. However, it's not clear that the reverse $EXP^{NP}\subseteq NEXP$ is true.
Are there any complexity theoretic conjectures which suggest this is not true and hence $EXP^{NP}\not=NEXP$?

Comment: Isn't it the other way around?

Comment: I don’t really understand what do you expect to get. $\mathrm{EXP^{NP}\ne NEXP}$ is itself a complexity theoretic conjecture. This is implied, for example, by $\mathrm{NEXP\ne coNEXP}$.

Comment: @M.Monet Isn’t what the other way round? But if you mean the inclusions, they are stated correctly in the question: $\mathrm{NEXP\subseteq EXP^{NP}}$ is true, while  $\mathrm{EXP^{NP}\subseteq NEXP}$ is likely false.

Comment: Oh yes sorry I read too fast. Should I delete the comments?

Comment: @user138901 - See my similar question here: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/41500/indications-that-strengthen-the-conjecture-nexp-%e2%8a%8a-expnp     There are many evidence that strengthen this conjecture, and I am still looking for more...

Comment: Thanks Avi, I must have missed this. I'll close this question given that it seems to be the same as yours.